# Getting location prop in the component where BrowserRouter is initialized

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am trying to make `react-router` work with `transition-group` but stumbled on the problem, that I can not access `location` prop directly in this component. Is there a solution that does not require creation of another child component that I would wrap into `withRouter` to access the `location`?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
        <React.Fragment>
          <Navigation language={"en"} />
          <Switch>
            <TransitionGroup>
             <CSSTransition location={this.props.location} timeout={300} classNames="fade"> 
              <Route
                path="/p"
                render={() => {
                  return (
                    <Layout>
                      <P/>
                    </Layout>
                  );
                }}
              />
              <Route
                path="/v"
                render={() => {
                  return (
                    <Layout>
                      <V/>
                    </Layout>
                  );
                }}
              />
             </CSSTransition> 
            </TransitionGroup>
          </Switch>
        </React.Fragment>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: A little confused here,can you describe your ideal situation more specifically

Comment: @Root So ideally I would need to get `location` but `this.props.location` does not work, because `App` component does not have this prop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While rendering the components using a `render` method, you need to pass on the Router props to the component being rendered like

```
   <Route
            path="/p"
            render={(props) => {
              return (
                <Layout {...props}>
                  <P/>
                </Layout>
              );
            }}
          />
          <Route
            path="/v"
            render={(props) => {
              return (
                <Layout {...props}>
                  <V/>
                </Layout>
              );
            }}
          />
```